# Show total Sum of values of a Column of a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datatable

I want to show sum of total Price of items. I am facing 2 issues:

- It's showing me wrong total of items price
- I want to add `.00` to the total price

You can check issue in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mvxF.jpg) for a clear explanation.

Here is my code:

```
tDisplay.Text = "Return/" + "Receipt No:" + Return_Form.setalueforText011;
label1.Text = Return_Form.setalueforText011;

OleDbConnection VCON = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Restaurant.accdb");
DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dsa.Tables.Add(dt);

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3] from [Total] Where [Receipt No] =  " + label1.Text + "", VCON);
da.Fill(dt);
//dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    products.Add(new tblProduct() { productName = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString(),productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString())))});
    label3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
    textBox59.Text = "Rs: "+String.Format("{0:}", Total);
    tblProduct selected = (tblProduct)(listBox60.SelectedItem);
    Total += (decimal)selected.productPrice;
}
VCON.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you add to the total always the SelectedItem row. This is always the first item so you end up doubling the value of the first item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Create and initialize a new tblProduct from the datatable row
    tblProduct current = new tblProduct();
    current.ProductName = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
    current.productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString())));

    // Add to your list of products
    products.Add(current);

    // This line is wrong because you overwrite the value at each loop
    label3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

    // Sum the price of the current tblProduct
    Total += (decimal)current.productPrice;
}
// Outside the loop update your total label
textBox59.Text = "Rs: "+String.Format("{0:0.00}", Total);
```

If you allow me to give an advice. Do not name your controls that way. They are unreadable and not easily recognizable. Looking at this code some day from now you will have a lot of problems to remember which control is textBox59 or listBox60.

Comment: Thank you so much sir i really thanksful to you,you are really killing genius person can i ask you a one  more question if you don't mind so about listbox

Comment: and one more thing i ask you in my first question how i add .00 with item price

Comment: This part of your question is unclear to me. I can't see how do you add items to the ListBox. However if you take the item from the  products list then you need to format them as you do now.

Comment: @michaeljohn Make `Total` variable a double and call `Total.ToString("0.00")`.

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. i am not asking about this listbox in my main form am using another listbox and i want when i click on button so all items forecolor changed in red and after this if i add another items in listbox so this items forecolor is black not change in red

Comment: Sorry but this is totally unrelated to your question. In this case I suggest you to post a new question detailing the problem. In this way more people will see you problem and can focus in one problem at time

Comment: Sorry but now am post a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414106/i-want-to-change-selected-item-forecolor-of-listbox

Answer (score 1):

***Sum***

Instead of using for loop, You can simply use [`Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx) method of data table and pass an expression to compute. For example:

```
var total = yourDataTable.Compute("SUM(Column1)", "");
```

***Format***

Also to format total to show 2 digits after decimal place, you can use either of these options:

- [The "0" Custom Numeric Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) : `string.Format("{0:0.00}", total))`
- [The Fixed-Point "F" format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4): `string.Format("{0:F2}", total))`

***Update Sum on changes of data***

Also to be able to show the sum automatically in a `TextBox` event when new items added or some items removed or some values changed, handle `ListChanged` event of `DataTable.DefaultView` and set the result as `Text` of the text box.

### Example

```
// Define data table
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));

// Fill data
dt.Rows.Add("Product 1", 100);
dt.Rows.Add("Product 2", 200);

// Set data source of data grid view
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

// Automatically update text box, by SUM of price
textBox1.Text = $"{dt.Compute("SUM(Price)", ""):F2}";
dt.DefaultView.ListChanged += (obj, args) =>
    textBox1.Text = $"{dt.Compute("SUM(Price)", ""):F2}";
```