# How to change ForeColor of SelectedItem in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, items

I am facing a little issue in my project how can I change fore-color of text of selected items in `ListBox`. I can select all items of `ListBox` but I don't know how to change fore-color of text of selected items.

This code am using in my project for select listbox items

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbProductsToBuy.Items.Count; i++)
{
     lbProductsToBuy.SetSelected(i,true);
}
printreceiptToken1();
dataGridView67.Rows.Clear();
```

Thanks. In these images you can see UI of my application. [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aPKW.png) and [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDOKJ.png). See this last image, I  want to change this selected items fore-color.

Comment: please hel;p me put your give me the best solution of this problem thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can set [`DrawMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ListBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and then hanlde [`DrawItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the control and draw items yourself:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var backColor = this.BackColor;         /*Default BackColor*/
    var textColor = this.ForeColor;         /*Default ForeColor*/
    var txt = listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[e.Index]);
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        backColor = Color.RoyalBlue;        /*Seletion BackColor*/
        textColor = Color.Yellow;           /*Seletion ForeColor*/
    }
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, listBox.Font, e.Bounds, textColor,
        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);
}
```

[image]

Comment: **1)** Maybe you forgot to `DrawMode` property of `ListBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed`  **2)** Maybe you forget to attach `listBox1_DrawItem` method to `DrawItem` event of your `ListBox`

Comment: sorry but you dont understand what i want

Comment: You are looking for setting forecolor of selected items.  aren't you? The post shows selected items using yellow forecolor.

Comment: i want when i click on button so all existing items of listbox forecolor change and after this if i add new item in that listbox so that items forecolor is black not change

Comment: That's the only way you can do this job and It's strange for me what part of the solution is not understandable for you. The post obviously answers your question. You need to select all items, so the colors of all items are yellow. Then if you deselect all items, all items will show in black color. Using an owner-draw list box is the only option when you use `ListBox`. Otherwise you should use ListView or DataGridView.