# Enumerate/iterate the rows of a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid instead of DataGridView. I know it's obsolete, but I'm using [a custom control that inherits from DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9947/DataGrid-with-built-in-filter-functionality) and it is too complicated to be ported to DataGridView without days of work.

I need to iterate through the rows but it doesn't have a `Rows` collection, so trying like

```
DataGrid grid = filterableGrid.EmbeddedDataGrid;
foreach (var row in grid.Rows)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

fails with this error:

```
'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method...
```

So how do I go about iterating it?

Comment: What do you want to do with that rows?

Comment: Calculate the sum of a column.

Comment: To show sum of values of a `Column` of `DataTable`, you can use `Compute` method of the `DataTable`. You may find this post useful: [Show total Sum of values of a Column of a DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38416170/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Read also the edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have hidden rows or columns you can iterate it using this code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < grid.VisibleRowCount; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < grid.VisibleColumnCount; column++)
    {
        var value = grid[row, column];
    }
}
```

If there are hidden rows and columns things become more complicated. You can iterate through rows and columns of [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) using the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.item?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) this way:

```
var rowsCount = grid.BindingContext[grid.DataSource, grid.DataMember].Count;
var columnsCount = ((DataGridTableStyle)(grid.GetType().GetField("myGridTable",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(grid))).GridColumnStyles.Count;

for (int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < columnsCount; column++)
    {
        var value = grid[row, column];
    }
}
```

Also if the `DataSource` of your `DataGrid` is a `DataTable`, you can use:

```
var table = grid.DataSource as DataTable;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: But won't this only return _visible_ rows and columns?

Comment: @Evk Yes, It needs a fix I'll post an edit, thank you :)

Comment: @Evk I edited the answer and used `rowsCount`  and `columnsCount` in the the most reliable way that I could. Let me know if you know a better option :)

Comment: Sine the `DataSource` may be a `List<T>` extracting columns count and rows count by converting the `DataSource` to a `DataTable` is not a good solution.

Comment: Yes this control is really poorly designed. Main point is question author sees the edit of course.