# How to show sum in label while searching datagridview using textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView With Lots of data in it and a search textbox.
My Problem is when i filter the datagridview rows i want my subtotal label to be changed according to search data but i am unable to do it because i am selecting the subtotal SUM with the query.

Here is My SubTotal Label Code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
string query = "SELECT SUM(Sub_Total) from (SELECT distinct Sub_Total FROM Sales_Order) as Sales_Order";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    Sub_Tot.Text = Convert.ToString(result); ;
}
con.Close();
```

Textbox Textchanged code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Invoice_no,Date_of_Sale,Customer_Name,Contact,Item_Code,Item_Name,Quantity,Selling_Price,Discount,Paid_Amount,Remaining,Sub_Total,Total From Sales_Order Order By Invoice_no", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dgv.DataSource = dt;

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_Name LIKE '{0}%' ", Search_By_ItemName.Text);
dgv.DataSource = dv;
```

Every thing works fine but its not changing SubTotal Text according to filter
I want to change my SubTotal label text according to search filter how is it possible?

Note: It's working perfectly using timer but i don't want to use timer

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Sale_Order_Grid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(Sale_Order_Grid.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
}
this.lbl_SubTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Search through the DataTable instead.

Comment: @jdweng any code example?

Comment: Something like this : List<DataRow> searchRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Customer_Name") == Search_By_ItemName.Text).ToList();

int sum = searchRows.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Paid_Amount"));

Comment: There are some ways to do this, but easy way is using `RowsAdded` event.

Comment: or in `DataBindingComplete`

Comment: I Tried `RowsAdded` event but not working.

Comment: You can initiate your grid in a method and then do sum in order, so you can loop over rows after binding , in order 1- First do search 2- Sum rows cell.

Comment: [Show total Sum of values of a Column of a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38413442/3110834)

Comment: @Usama, What is your opinion about answer?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, If I understand you correctly you want to fill `subtotal` label according your search query not looping over your grid and sum that column one by one ? yes?

if true you can use sum aggregate in your T-Sql and get it from `DataTable` columns, something like :

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Invoice_no,Date_of_Sale,Customer_Name,Contact,Item_Code,Item_Name,Quantity,Selling_Price,Discount,Paid_Amount,Remaining,Sub_Total,Total,SUM(Sub_Total) as SubTotal From Sales_Order Group by Invoice_no,Date_of_Sale,Customer_Name,Contact,Item_Code,Item_Name,Quantity,Selling_Price,Discount,Paid_Amount,Remaining,Sub_Total,Total Order By Invoice_no", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dgv.DataSource = dt;

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_Name LIKE '{0}%' ", Search_By_ItemName.Text);
dgv.DataSource = dv;
```

getting your col value by field name:

```
var totlaCol= dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().SingleOrDefault(col => col.ColumnName == "SubTotal");
if (totalCol!= null)
{
    var tableRows = dt.AsEnumerable().First();
    var sumVal= tableRows.Field<string>(totlaCol);
    // or 
    //sumVal = tableRows.Field<string>(dt.Columns.IndexOf(myColumn));
}
```

1- Note if you used `Sum` you should  `Group by` your selected cols.

2- You can use separate query to just select sum col and use separate `DataTable`

3- I didn't test it before but I sure this way give you your expect output.