# How to get sum of datagridview column to a textbox without any button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have put some values in a `DataGridView` and want to get sum of its columns to some `TextBox`es. I want when I enter the data to `DataGridView`, sum of those specific columns should automatically put to related textboxes.

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: [Show total Sum of values of a Column of a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416170/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to `CellValueChanged` event on `DataGridView` and do calculation there.

Here exemple of what it might look like:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  // Determine what column has changed
  var colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
  var sum = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    // Be aware of what numbers you have in your column!!
    // Then cast it appropriately
    sum += (int)row.Cells[colIndex].Value;
  textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

**NOTE**: I used default names of controls, generated by designer. Change them accordignly to your names.